# Is it possible to use kotlinx-datetime with Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, kotlinx

I have JSON data which is retrieved from the local realm database. I'm trying to convert it into the corresponding data class. I have an ISO date field

```
{
  ....
  "createdAt" : "2022-05-04T10:16:56.489Z"
  ....

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert this string date field into `kotlinx-datetime`'s `Instant` object which is a serializable class. Thus I made my data class as

```
import kotlinx.datetime.Instant

data class PollPinComment(
    ...
    val createdAt: Instant? = null,
    ...
)
```

Which doesn't work and gives an error as follows

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 288 path $[0].createdAt
```

I'm sure that I might need to write some serialization/deserialization logic with gson to convert this string into `Instant` object. So my question is how can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `Deserializer` for this and register it as `type adapter` to your `Gson` object.

```
class InstantDateDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?, 
        typeOfT: Type?, 
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): Instant? {
        return json?.asString?.let {
            Instant.parse(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Create `Gson()` object pasing that `deserializer` as `type adapter`

```
val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder ()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Instant::class.java, InstantDateDeserializer())
    .create()
```

---

If you are using it with `Retrofit`

In `Retrofit` builder pass this to `GsonConverterFactory`

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

GSON parses only basic data types, such as Int, String, double...
Other classes that need to be parsed must also consist of these basic data types.
could do like this:

```
 data class PollPinComment(val createdAt: String ){

 fun  getCreatedAt(): Instant{
     return  Instant.parse(createdAt) 
 }
 }
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, but can't we create and use GsonFactory to achieve the same?